# 一 [份/个/项] 工作??? What is the difference?

Tags: measure-word

Not sure if there is actually a difference, but I see the word 工作 used with different measure words and I've never got to the bottom of what the difference is. I recently saw 换一份工作， so I guess that is to change jobs, i.e. to change to work for a different company?
But how does that compare to 一项工作? Is that the same? Or is that more like a piece of work within the same job? I.e. I've got two projects at work and I work on project A in the morning and project B in the afternoon, so at lunchtime I 换一项工作?!! Or am I just making that up?!
And what of 个? Are there are other measure words you can use with 工作?
All input happily welcomed :-)
Hashamyim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so simple way to put this:

一份工作：it means a job (occupation)

一项工作：it means a task

工作 has many meanings, so depending on the context, it means different things.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[份/个/项] is not important, in other word the three 字s are similar-meaning words. You can say "一份工作" or "一个工作" and all Chineses
will acknowledge what you say.
Extra: 项 with 工作 is not common in Spoken Chinese, maybe the 工作 followed 项 refers to project.

> I recently saw 换一份工作， so I guess that is to change jobs, i.e. to change to work for a different company?

There is also another correct situation that You become Apple's boss from Apple's Manager.